# Windows batch file to list all duplicates (and the original file) in tree and sort them

Tags: windows, batch-file, duplicates

I have to check a tree for duplicating files and write all of them to List.txt file.
But my script seems to skip one of the file locations in each group. (For example, if there are 4 duplicating files, only 3 of them appear in the list.)

If I'm not mistaken, it's the location of the "previousFile" of the last comparison that is missing. How do I write it to the list, too?

Also, how can I group paths in the List.txt by the filename so that it looks something like this:

File fileNameA.txt : 
C:\path1\fileNameA.txt
C:\path2\fileNameA.txt
C:\path3\fileNameA.txt

File fileNameB.txt : 
C:\path1\fileNameB.txt
C:\path2\fileNameB.txt
C:\path3\fileNameB.txt
C:\path4\fileNameB.txt

File fileNameC.txt : 
C:\path1\fileNameC.txt
C:\path2\fileNameC.txt

...

?

That's my script so far:

```
@echo off

setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set root=%1

IF EXIST List.txt del /F List.txt

set "prevTest=none"
set "prevFile=none"

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%A in (
  '"(for /r "%root%" %%F in (*) do @echo %%~zF:%%~fF:)|sort"'
) do (
  set "currentTest=%%A"
  set "currentFile=%%B:%%C"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "match="
  if !currentTest! equ !previousTest! fc /b "!previousFile!" "!currentFile!" >nul && set match=1
  if defined match (
    echo File "!currentFile!" >> List.txt
    endlocal
  ) else (
    endlocal
    set "previousTest=%%A"
    set "previousFile=%%B:%%C"
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *count* matches and add `echo` *previous* filename  to `echo` *current* one in case of the first match.

Note `'"(for /r "%root%" %%F in (*) do @echo(%%~nxF?%%~zF?%%~fF?)|sort"'` changes:

- used `?` (question mark) as a delimiter:  reserved character by [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)
- added `%%~nxF?` prefix to `sort` output properly by file names even in my sloppy test folder structure, see sample output below.

This output shows than even `cmd` poisonous characters (like `&`, `%`, `!` etc.) in file names are handled properly with `DisableDelayedExpansion` kept.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "root=%~1"
if not defined root set "root=%CD%"

set "previousTest="
set "previousFile="
set "previousName="
set "match=0"

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=?" %%A in (
  '"(for /r "%root%" %%F in (*) do @echo(%%~nxF?%%~zF?%%~fF?x)|sort"'
) do (
    set "currentName=%%A"
    set "currentTest=%%B"
    set "currentFile=%%C"
    Call :CompareFiles
)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:CompareFiles
  if /I "%currentName%" equ "%previousName%" ( set /A "match+=1" ) else ( set "match=0" )
  if %match% GEQ 1 (
      if %match% EQU 1 echo FILE "%previousFile%" %previousTest%
      echo      "%currentFile%" %currentTest%
  ) else (
      set "previousName=%currentName%"
      set "previousTest=%currentTest%"
      set "previousFile=%currentFile%"
  )
goto :eof
```

Above script lists all files of duplicated *names* regardless of their size and content. Sample output:

```
FILE "d:\bat\cliPars\cliParser.bat" 1078
     "d:\bat\files\cliparser.bat" 12303
     "d:\bat\Unusual Names\cliparser.bat" 12405
     "d:\bat\cliparser.bat" 335
FILE "d:\bat\Stack33721424\BÄaá^ cčD%OS%Ď%%OS%%(%1!)&°~%%G!^%~2.foo~bar.txt" 120
     "d:\bat\Unusual Names\BÄaá^ cčD%OS%Ď%%OS%%(%1!)&°~%%G!^%~2.foo~bar.txt" 120
```

To list all files of duplicated *names* with the same *size* but regardless of their content:

```
:CompareFiles
  REM if /I "%currentName%" equ "%previousName%" (
  if /I "%currentTest%%currentName%" equ "%previousTest%%previousName%" (
      set /A "match+=1"
      REM fc /b "%previousFile%" "%currentFile%" >nul && set /A "match+=1"
  ) else ( set "match=0" )
```

To list all files of duplicated *names* with the same *size* and binary *content*:

```
:CompareFiles
  REM if /I "%currentName%" equ "%previousName%" (
  if /I "%currentTest%%currentName%" equ "%previousTest%%previousName%" (
      REM set /A "match+=1"
      fc /b "%previousFile%" "%currentFile%" >nul && set /A "match+=1"
  ) else ( set "match=0" )
```

**Edit** If the name of the file doesn't matter (only its contents), you could apply next changes in `FOR` loop and in `:CompareFiles` subroutine:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "root=%~1"
if not defined root set "root=%CD%"

set "previousTest="
set "previousFile="
set "match=0"

for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=?" %%A in (
  '"(for /r "%root%" %%F in (*) do @echo(%%~zF?%%~fF?)|sort"'
) do (
    set "currentTest=%%A"
    set "currentFile=%%B"
                                     rem optional: skip all files of zero length
    if %%A GTR 0 Call :CompareFiles
)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:CompareFiles
  if /I "%currentTest%" equ "%previousTest%" (
      fc /b "%previousFile%" "%currentFile%" >nul && set /A "match+=1"
  ) else ( set "match=0" )
  if %match% GEQ 1 (
      if %match% EQU 1 echo FILE "%previousFile%" %previousTest%
      echo      "%currentFile%" %currentTest%
  ) else (
      set "previousTest=%currentTest%"
      set "previousFile=%currentFile%"
  )
goto :eof
```

Comment: What does an `x` in the end of `%%~fF?x` do? Or is it a mistype? I tried to remove it or change it to something else, and the output is still the same.

Comment: @0lesya Trailing `x` in `%%~nxF?%%~zF?%%~fF?x` is a mistype (some debugging residual). In fact, any string there does not matter as we take `"tokens=1-3 delims=?"`. Hence, `%%~nxF?%%~zF?%%~fF?` is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: If the name of the file doesn't matter (only its contents), I should use  `/I "%currentTest%" equ "%previousTest%" (` instead of `if /I "%currentTest%%currentName%" equ "%previousTest%%previousName%" (`, right?

Comment: @0lesya see my edit: newly added script should find and show all files of the same _binary content_ regardless of their names skiping files of zero length. --- And a correction of my previous comment: `%%~nxF?%%~zF?%%~fF` is necessary and sufficient for parsing with `"tokens=1-3 delims=?"` (no trailing delimiter `?`). However, I'd keep it there in sake of clear readability…